# Waiting for GUI events and IOCP notifications at once

Tags: windows, iocp, message-loop

Can I wait for GUI events — that is, pump a message loop — and on an I/O completion port at the same time?  I would like to integrate libuv with the Windows GUI.

Comment: not exist api call which let you at once wait for I/O completion port and GUI events. you need how minimum 2 separate threads for this

Comment: @RbMm can it be done with the undocumented Native API?

Comment: even with undocumented Native API - no. and by sense - on iocp usually wait thread pool, gui thread have separate tasks. for what you need use only single thread for iocp and combine it with gui ?

Comment: @RbMm Using Node.js or similar in a GUI.  I cannot run JS code on any thread but the main thread.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are two solutions that I know of.  One works on all versions of Windows, but involves multiple threads.  The other is faster, but only supports Windows 10+ (thank you @RbMm for this fact).

1. Another thread calls `GetQueuedCompletionStatusEx` in a loop, and sends messages to the main thread with `SendMessage`.  The main thread reads the messages from it's message loop, notes the custom message type, and dispatches the I/O completions.

   This solution works on all versions of Windows, but is slower.  However, if one is willing to trade latency for throughput, one can increase the `GetQueuedCompletionStatusEx` receive buffer to recover nearly the same throughput as the second solution.  For best performance, both threads should use the same CPU, to avoid playing cache ping-pong with the I/O completions.
2. The main thread uses `MsgWaitForMultipleObjectsEx` to wait for the completion port to be signaled or user input to arrive.  Once it is signaled, the main thread calls `GetQueuedCompletionStatusEx` with a zero timeout.

   This assumes that an IOCP that is used by only one thread becomes signaled precisely when an I/O completion arrives.  This is only true on Windows 10 and up.  Otherwise, you will busyloop, since the IOCP will always be signaled.  On systems that support this method, it should be faster, since it reduces scheduling overhead.

Comment: unfortunately 2 will be work only begin from win 10. in all previous windows versions any wait on iocp just return 0 (object is signaled) regardless of real state of iocp. this is  because system wait not on your iocp itself but on common *default object* for iocp type.

Comment: @RbMm Thank you.  I will add that to my answer.

Comment: begin from win10 system wait on iocp itself and this begin work. on yet win8.1 system wait on common default object for iocp type